# scala implicit delegation vs inheritance

Tags: scala

Salutations, SO!

I'm obviously some species of a scala noob. I was intrigued from the beginning by the possibility to express those tedious delegations via implicits and thought it was cool to use them throughout .

My issue is that type tests no longer worked as they would with inheritance. See bellow code, 'false' is printed 4 times (unsurprinsingly)

```
trait T { def bar = Unit }
class A { def aFoo() = print("AFooooo") }
class B { def bFoo() = print("BFooooo") }

object Ca { implicit def delToA(me : Ca) : A = me.a}
class Ca(val a : A) extends T { }

object Cb { implicit def delToB(me : Cb) : B = me.b}
class Cb(val b : B) extends T { }

object MyName extends App {
  val ca : T = new Ca(new A)
  val cb : T = new Cb(new B)

  println(ca.isInstanceOf[A])
  println(ca.isInstanceOf[B])

  println( cb.isInstanceOf[A])
  println(cb.isInstanceOf[B])
}
```

Is thee any way to be able to test that a T is either an A or a B underneath? And a way to bind it to an A or a B variable, of course.
Another way, not inheritance.

And.. is there some obvious reason why false is always the result of isInstanceOf? The code could have very well resulted in : true false false true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Type tests like `isInstanceOf` will not use implicit conversions to try to convert to the type you're testing it against. When you say `ca.isInstanceOf[A]`, `ca` *must* be an instance of `A` in order to be `true`. `ca` and `cb` are not instances of `A` or `B`, so all tests should return `false` as expected.

This is because implicits are resolved at compile time, but `isInstanceOf` as checked a runtime. There's no way we can mix the two like that.

You can use a compile-time check to see that something can be implicitly viewable as something else.

```
implicit class Wrapper[A](a: A) {
    def isImplicitly[B](implicit ev: A => B): Boolean = true
}

class Y
class Z

implicit def z2y(z: Z): Y = new Y

val y = new Y
val z = new Z

scala> z.isImplicitly[Y]
res66: Boolean = true

scala> y.isImplicitly[Z]
<console>:39: error: No implicit view available from Y => Z.
              y.isImplicitly[Z]
                            ^
```

But this is fundamentally different as it doesn't really return true/false, it just fails to compile if it's not true. And it still wouldn't work for your example. Since `ca` is a `T`, the compiler wouldn't even try to implicitly convert from `T => A` because the conversion is defined for `Ca => A`. It wouldn't know at compile time that `Ca` is a `Ca`, nor which companion object to find the required implicit in.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Your answer cleared the crucial runtime/compile time difference. I'm barely scratching the surface for implicit usage at the moment. It seems they're not worth it for what I'm trying to do. Paul Phillips named them (directly or he was quoting smbd) a programable typesystem so surely anyone would want that!

Comment: Also your example was quite neat but introduced implicit classes and I've no clue what to make of those.

Comment: @CristianMartin I wouldn't worry about the implicit example for now. The gist of the answer is that you can't use implicits for runtime checks. Nor is it trivial to compare exact runtime types either. I can think of some reflection hacks to make it *sort of* work by inspecting the inheritance tree, but I doubt that's a good road to go down.